# Accessing objects/methods outside of a loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm trying to access objects/methods outside of a this loop for a simple HTTP server coded with Ruby:

```
require 'socket'                # Get sockets from stdlib

class Hello
  def say_hi 
    "Hello, world!"
  end
end

hi = Hello.new
server = TCPServer.open(2000)   # Socket to listen on port 2000
loop {                          # Servers run forever
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    client.puts(hi.say_hi)
    client.close                # Disconnect from the client
  end
}
```

It looks like the request just hangs because "hi" and its "say_hi" method cannot be accessed outside the loop. How to I access objects, modules, methods so I can use them for my simple server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code you provided works fine. I was able to run the server, connect through `telnet localhost 2000` and receive the "Hello, world!" message before the connection closed.

There are times when a block won't have access to the local scope surrounding it. That isn't the case in your example, but if you are encountering it elsewhere there are ways around it.

Constants and globals are visible globally. You could assign your `Hello` instance variable to a global: `$hi = Hello.new`, though most developers will tell you using globals is "bad". You could modify your `Hello` class so that it contains a registry of instances:

```
require 'socket'                # Get sockets from stdlib

class Hello
  def initialize(name)
    self.class.registry[name] = self
  end

  def say_hi 
    "Hello, world!"
  end

  def self.registry
    @@registry ||= {}
  end
end

Hello.new(:hi)
server = TCPServer.open(2000)   # Socket to listen on port 2000
loop {                          # Servers run forever
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    client.puts(Hello.registry[:hi].say_hi)
    client.close                # Disconnect from the client
  end
}
```

There are other ways to overcome scope issues as well, including passing the `hi` instance to `Thread.start`, using [thread local variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Thread.html#class-Thread-label-Thread+variables+and+scope), and others. Hard to suggest a specific when the supplied code already works.

Comment: Thank you! This was a simplified version of my problem, but making the object a global variable fixed the problem. Now I can work on finding a better way than using a global.

Answer (score 2):

It's working as expected. When you call server.accept it blocks waiting for a client to connect. You can confirm this by starting up your program and telnetting to it, e.g.:

```
telnet localhost 2000
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello, world!
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Notice the server responded with "Hello, world!"